# C implementation for C++ strings & vector of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I've some C++ APIs like below:

```
API1(std::string str, std::vector<std::string> vecofstr);
```

**I want to call this API from a C code. How can i provide a C wrapper for this ?**

`std::string str` 
**=>**

> I can probably use char* for std::string

&

`std::vector<std::string> vecofstr` => 
array of char* for vector of string like

> char* arrOfstrings[SIZE];

Comment: hmm, the `std::vector` is passed in as a copy...

Comment: so yeah perhaps...

Comment: I would use: `API1_Wrapper(const char* str, const char** vecofstr, size_t vecSize);`

Comment: ^ that, wrapped in `extern "C" {}`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what the corresponding C header (and its C++ implementation) could look like:

### Declaration

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void cAPI1(const char *str, const char * const *vecofstr, size_t vecofstrSize);
```

### Implementation

```
extern "C" void cAPI1(const char *str, const char * const *vecofstr, size_t vecofstrSize)
{
  API1(str, {vecofstr, vecofstr + vecofstrSize});
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31e8450ee3a6c179)

The above assumes that the C code will use zero-terminated strings for all string arguments. If that is not the case, the parameters of `cAPI1` must be modified accordingly (ideally based on what representation of strings is actually used by the C code).

Comment: There is an assumption here that `str` and the elements of `vecofstr` are all C-strings (i.e. terminated with a character with value zero).   Otherwise, your code yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the syntax: {vecofstr + vecofstrSize} in the C implementation. How can this be assigned to the vector::string in C++ counterpart ?

Comment: @codeLover - If you aren't sure how is it allowed to initialize a vector, your first stop should be the [documentation of `std::vector`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: @codeLover Note that as the answer says, the function `cAPI1` needs a C++ implementation, not a C one. The syntax is `{vec, vec + size}`, which simply invokes the 2-iterator constructor of `std::vector`.

Comment: Worth noting: this C API copies each of the passed C-style strings into  std::string's before calling the C++ API

Comment: In modern C you would rather write `void cAPI1(const char *str, const, size_t vSize, char* vecofstr[vSize])`. Pointer-to-pointer usually indicates that you intend to return a pointer, so it is misleading.

Comment: @dats Which would happen in the C++ case as well, since `API1` takes all of its parameters by value.

Comment: @Lundin I admit I know very little actual C, so I approached this from the C++ side. Feel free to post a proper C answer.

Comment: `const char* const*`, please, not just `const char**`.

Comment: @Angew:  "const char* const* " means constant char string pointer to a constant char string data. But the c++ vector need not be a const right ? We can edit the vector values ? SO why is the const needed ?

Comment: @codeLover In your original code, the vector is passed by value, so the function cannot change the vector used as argument at the call site. The same should hold of the C function.

Comment: @Angew: If i pass a vector by value then the callee function is free to change the values of this vector copy. Isn't it ? i just tried using below code & i could change  vs[0] = "one_c"; 

void fun(vector<string> vs)
{
 vs[0] = "one_c";
}
int main()
{
 vector<string> vecstr = { "one", "two" };
 fun(vecstr);
}

Comment: @Lundin: Using void cAPI1(const char *str, const, size_t vSize, char* vecofstr[vSize]) , compiler complains that "a parameter is not alowed' on "vSize" in char* vecofstr[vSize].

Comment: @codeLover You need to compile C code with a conforming C compiler. VS is a non-conforming C++ compiler.

Answer (score -3):

1.api.h

```
#ifndef API_H_
#define API_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void api1(std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& vecofstr);

#endif
```

.2. api.cpp

```
#include "api.h"
#include <iostream>

void api1(std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& vecofstr) {
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  for (size_t i=0; i<vecofstr.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << vecofstr[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

3.wrapper.h

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H_
#define WRAPPER_H_

#define SIZE 2

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  extern void wrapper1(char* p, char* [SIZE]);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
#endif
```

4.wrapper.cpp

```
#include <string>

#include "wrapper.h"
#include "api.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void wrapper1(char* p, char* ps[SIZE]) {
  std::string str(p);
  std::vector<std::string> vecofstr;
  for (size_t idx=0; idx<SIZE; idx++) {
    vecofstr.push_back(ps[idx]);
  }
  api1(str, vecofstr);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

.5. test.c

```
#include "wrapper.h"

int main(void)
{
  char* p = "hello world";
  char* ps[] = {"world", "hello"};
  wrapper1(p, ps);
  return 0;
}
```

.6. compile

```
gcc -c api.cpp wrapper.cpp
gcc test.c -o test wrapper.o api.o -lstdc++
```

.7. run

```
./test
hello world
world
hello
```